# Woocommerce Display a short description in the order overview via the Permalink Product Link in order-details-item.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to have the respective short description of the product / article displayed in WOOCOMMERCE in the order overview "Order-Details-Item" (template / woocommerce / order / order-details-item.php) about the product Permalink.

I found the following code on the web to allow a brief description.
Here is the code for this:

```
<div class="product_short_description_cart_default">
 <?php
 $product_id = $_product->get_parent_id();
 $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    echo $product->get_short_description();
 ?>
 </div>
```

But how do I incorporate them into my order-details-item.php file?
Here is the code for this:

```html
<?php
/**
 * Order Item Details
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/order/order-details-item.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.7.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit;
}

if ( ! apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_visible', true, $item ) ) {
 return;
}
?>
<tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'woocommerce-table__line-item order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">

 <td class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name">
  <div class="order-details-item-default-product-name-left">
  <?php
  echo '<div class="product-image">'.$product->get_image(array( 80, 80)).'</div>';
  $is_visible        = $product && $product->is_visible();
  $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_permalink', $is_visible ? $product->get_permalink( $item ) : '', $item, $order );
  ?>
  </div>
  <div class="order-details-item-default-product-name-right">
  <?php
  echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $product_permalink ? sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $product_permalink, $item->get_name() ) : $item->get_name(), $item, $is_visible ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped

  $qty          = $item->get_quantity();
  $refunded_qty = $order->get_qty_refunded_for_item( $item_id );

  if ( $refunded_qty ) {
   $qty_display = '<del>' . esc_html( $qty ) . '</del> <ins>' . esc_html( $qty - ( $refunded_qty * -1 ) ) . '</ins>';
  } else {
   $qty_display = esc_html( $qty );
  }

  echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity_html', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times; %s', $qty_display ) . '</strong>', $item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped

  do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order, false );

  wc_display_item_meta( $item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped

  do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order, false );
  
  // SKU mit Sprachdatei          
  echo '<div class="cart-sku-item">' . __( "SKU:", "woostroid") . $product->sku . '</div>';
  
  ?>
  </div>
 </td>

 <td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total">
  <?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
 </td>

</tr>

<?php if ( $show_purchase_note && $purchase_note ) : ?>

<tr class="woocommerce-table__product-purchase-note product-purchase-note">

 <td colspan="2"><?php echo wpautop( do_shortcode( wp_kses_post( $purchase_note ) ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></td>

</tr>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Can you please help me there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place below code in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'display_product_title_as_link', 10, 2 );
    function display_product_title_as_link( $item_name, $item ) {

        $_product = get_product( $item['variation_id'] ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'] );


        $_var_description ='';

        if ( $item['variation_id'] ) {
            $_var_description = $_product->get_variation_description();
        }else{
            $_var_description = $_product->get_short_description();
        } 

        return $_var_description.'<br>'.$item_name;
    }
```

Comment: You can remove  anchor if does not need

Comment: Hello lakshman rajput, 
With the help of your idea, I was able to continue researching and found a solution that at least gives me the SHORT DESCRIPTION.
I just have to adjust them accordingly! 

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'add_single_excerpt_to_order_item', 10, 3 );
function add_single_excerpt_to_order_item( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ){
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // Get the product Id
    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $product_id ); // Get the short description

    return $item_name . '<br><p class="item-description">' . $excerpt ; '</p>';
}`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your efforts and for the great code.

But did we talk past each other ?!

So I would like to have the following displayed next to the product image:

1. Product short description
2. Product name with link
3. Design / (variants of products)
4. Item number (SKU NUMBER)

points 2 and 3 and 4 work.

I only miss the first point (product short description) (echo $ product-> get_short_description ();)

Excuse me for my first bad description.